# trying to search cell and sending the cell info to other function

Tags: java

Hey i am trying to make a code that check if 2 cells are match and then return the cell. Then using the cell next to it to change numbers.

```
function findString() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange(4,4,5,1).getValues();
  var findCell = new Array();
  findCell.push(data[0])  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if(data==SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetValues(5,9,1,1))
    break
  }
  i++;
  return (i,5) ;
}

function modifyCell2(cellname2) {
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(findString())
  var toRemove = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetValues(6,9,1,1)

  range2.setValue(range2.getValue() - toRemove);
}

function minusDKP() {
  modifyCell2(findString());
}
```

The cells i am searching is at d4:d9 range. The cell i want to change is in e4:e9 range. The cell i search with is in i6.

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: i think google sheets uses java

Comment: You think, but this looks like `Javascript`